# How do I send stream of chunks with hyper?

Tags: rust, hyper

I have some working code with hyper 0.14 that looks roughly like this – very simplified code but basically I need the sender end of this channel to be able to data into the body:

```
let (sender, body) = Body::channel();

let request = Request::builder()
    .method(Method::POST)
    .uri("http://localhost:3000/")
    .header("content-type", "text")
    .body(body)
    .unwrap();

let client = Client::new();

let response = client.request(request);

tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut sender = sender;

    println!(
        "Body: {:?}",
        sender.send_data(hyper::body::Bytes::from("test\n")).await
    );
    println!(
        "Body: {:?}",
            sender.send_data(hyper::body::Bytes::from("test2\n")).await
        );
    });

    println!("{:?}", response.await);
```

I am trying to upgrade the code to hyper 1.0 and not quite sure how to do the equivalent – I'm attempting to create an mpsc channel. The code below is not working but I'm not even sure if I'm on the correct track of trying to use `StreamBody` with `ReceiverStream`

```
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Frame<Bytes>>(100);

let stream: ReceiverStream<hyper::body::Frame<bytes::Bytes>> = ReceiverStream::new(rx);

let body: StreamBody<ReceiverStream<hyper::body::Frame<bytes::Bytes>>> =
    StreamBody::new(stream);

let boxed_body = body.boxed(); //compile errors here

let request = Request::builder()
    .method(Method::POST)
    .uri("http://localhost/test")
    .body(boxed_body)
    .unwrap();
let response = client.request(request);
tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut sender = sender;

    println!(
        "Body: {:?}",
        sender.send(Frame::data(Bytes::from("test\n"))).await
    );
    println!(
        "Body: {:?}",
        sender.send(Frame::data(Bytes::from("test2\n"))).await
    );
});

println!("{:?}", response.await);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by referring to the official example, this code can be compiled.

[Refer to hyper official example](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/examples/send_file.rs)

```
 //change channel Item type to MyResult<Bytes>
type MyResult<T> = std::result::Result<T,std::io::Error>;
let (mut tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<MyResult<Bytes>>(100);

//convert to match BoxBody
let stream_body = StreamBody::new(stream.map_ok(Frame::data));
let boxed_body = stream_body.boxed();
```

Comment: But  i found whether it is hyper version 0.14 or version 1.1, the channel stream body cannot respond in real time.

Comment: Look at the questions I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932543/how-to-output-in-real-time-with-hyper-stream-response-body